# Javascript library without using an import in the script tag

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, es6-modules, script-tag

I try to create a library using typescript and I would like to use a static method that allows me to render some HTML content that is returned to me by an api rest call based on the parameters I pass to that function now there is a way to create it using a architecture eg pattern repository, compile it and then use it as in the code below (in js format of course)?

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script scr="../myLybrary.js"></script>
<script type="module">

    MyLibrary.render({
        param: "test",
        param1: "test",
        param2: "test"
    }, "test")

</script>
```

at the moment to create this situation I have to use an import in the script where the call to the static method resides in this way:

```
import MyLibrary from './myLybrary.js'
```

is there any way to avoid this last step?

Thanks to anyone who wants to help me.

Answer (score 2):

> at the moment to create this situation I have to use an import in the script where the call to the static method resides in this way:
>
> ```
> import MyLibrary from './myLybrary.js'
> ```

That would generally be the right thing to do. You'd just remove the first `script` tag, since with it you'll end up loading your library twice. So that leaves us with:

```html
<div id="test"></div>

<!-- Note: No `script` tag for `myLybrary.js` here. -->
<script type="module">
    import MyLibrary from "./myLybrary.js";

    MyLibrary.render({
        param: "test",
        param1: "test",
        param2: "test"
    }, "test");

</script>
```

Loading a module runs the top-level code in the module, so if `myLybrary.js` has top-level code that loads some resource, that code will be run when the `import` declaration is processed.

Comment: the fact is that the library is made available to users via cdn and it will not be possible to download it from npm for this reason I need to be able to try above all the first and try to remove the second, provided that it is obviously feasible ...

Comment: @Maury8788 - There's no reason you can't load a module from a CDN, e.g.: `import MyLibrary from "https://some-cdn.net/myLybrary.js";`

Comment: wow I did not know this thing I try to test it then, does it fit you as a development method for this type of case or do you have to recommend some other method?

Comment: @Maury8788 - For me it's the same as any other time you load code from a CDN. It has the advantage that it's coming from a CDN, which probably has edge locations and so will be very fast; it has the disadvantage that if the CDN is down or inaccessible, your page won't work. The fact it's a module doesn't matter. But separately, I wouldn't expect a *library* to trigger a side-effect on load (downloading resources from elsewhere). Instead, I'd expect it to offer some kind of initialization method that I'd call to do that. So that part is a bit unusual (to me).